# Unlocked cells go back to locked whenever I drag and drop a link from a browser

Tags: excel

I have a protected spreadsheet where some cells are unlocked to allow users to fill them up. The problem is that whenever they drag and drop a hyperlink from the browser to the unlocked cell somehow the cell changes to locked so the content of the cell can’t be edited or removed unless the spreadsheet is unprotected. Does anybody have any clue on how to prevent this from happening? Thanks

Comment: Obviously, you are copying the cell formatting from the source to your sheet (together with its value). If you don't want that, don't drag. Try Copy/Paste or Paste Special. If you do need to drag and know that the cell's format isn't what you want, change the format after dragging.

Comment: Problem is not the formatting tho but the cell going locked for some reason while was clearly unlocked when I protected the sheet.

Comment: The `Locked` property is one of the cell's properties, part of the formatting. We don't know the source of your data but that's where the property setting comes from. If you insist on dragging (meaning import the source cell's setting - if it's a cell) you might run an event procedure that unlocks the cell whenever a change occurs in it. But that would make your workbook macro-enabled which may pose another problem for you.